# Cálculo de datas: data de hoje, do new Date() e data extraída do GoogleSpreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Estou tentando subtrair duas datas. A data de hoje, usando o new Date(), e uma data de uma planilha do googledocs(foto). A coluna F que armazena as datas do googledocs está no formato de data dd/mm/yyyy. Ao executar o script, tenho o erro TypeError: Não é possível encontrar a função getTime no objeto . (linha 21, arquivo "Código")
A linha 21 está destacada embaixo, e vi que o problema está na variável dFim(que armazena a data da tabela), pois quando removi ela, o código executou sem erro.
Essa variável armazena o valor lido da coluna F. Estou usando o getTime() para obter os milissegundos do intervalo e dividi-los pelo milissegundos de um dia como diz o manual e não sei onde posso estar errando?

```
function myFunction() {
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  var today = new Date();

  for (var i = 4; i < values.length; i++) {
    var dFim = values[i][5];
    var dias = (today.getTime() - dFim.getTime()) / 86400000; //linha 21

      if (dias > 0) {
        Logger.log('Projeto atrasado')

  } else {

        Logger.log('Projeto no prazo')
   }
 }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta converter o valor vindo da planilha em objeto `Date()`:

```
var dFim = new Date(values[i][5]);
```

Com os dois objetos, não precisa dividir por `86400000` para ver se é maior que `0`, basta verificar se um é maior que o outro.

Então ficará assim:

```
function myFunction() {
   ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var dataRange = ss.getDataRange();
   var values = dataRange.getValues();

   var today = new Date();

   for (var i = 4; i < values.length; i++) {
      var dFim = new Date(values[i][5]);

      if (today.getTime() > dFim.getTime()) {
         Logger.log('Projeto atrasado')

      } else {

         Logger.log('Projeto no prazo')
      }
   }
}
```

**Exemplo para teste:**

```js
// data de hoje (06/03/2019) apenas para teste
var today = new Date(2019, 2, 6);
var values = [
   'Fri Feb 15 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2019', // atrasado
   'Wed Mar 06 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2019', // no prazo
   'Wed Mar 07 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2019' // no prazo
];


for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   var dFim = new Date(values[i]);

   if (today.getTime() > dFim.getTime()) {
      console.log('Projeto atrasado')
   } else {
      console.log('Projeto no prazo')
   }
}
```

Comment: Se eu insiro uma data diretamente como você fez, '07/03/2019', ele executa normal. Porém, da forma como está o primeiro código, me retorna o erro: TypeError: Não é possível encontrar a função split no objeto Fri Feb 15 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST). (linha 10, arquivo "Código")
Essa data é da planilha

Comment: Entendi... vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Faz o seguinte: coloca um `console.log(dFim);` após a linha `var dFim = values[i][5];` e me diz o que mostra.

Comment: Tenta assim: deixe seu código como estava, apenas altere esta linha: `var dFim = new Date(values[i][5]);`

Comment: Vê o lance do console que comentei mais acima.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90708/discussion-between-sam-and-roger-roger).

Comment: Resolvido, alterando a variável dFim para  var dFim = new Date(values[i][5]), como sugerido no chat e acima. Muito obrigado.